# Really slow cypher query (neo4j)

Tags: neo4j

When executing the following cypher query:

```
START me=node(2) MATCH (me)-[:likes]->page<-[:likes]-(person) WHERE NOT(me-[:isFriendOf]-person) RETURN person
```

I am observing the following execution times:

```
163ms
173ms
177ms
210ms
174ms
etc.
```

The graph consist of 6 user nodes, 6 page nodes and a total of 12 relationships:

- Person isFriendOf Person;
- Person likes Page;

This doesn't look like normal behaviour. What could be the root cause of this?

Comment: could you share your create statement so that I can test it locally? You could use 'dump' in neo4j-shell (neo4j V2) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

The performance issue was caused by using not a global or 
threadlocal ExecutionEngine.
Do not create an ExecutionEngine per request but always thread local (or global) otherwise you will kill the cache.